# Entity Framework Core creates unnecessary foreign key for owned type when using TPT mapping strategy

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When I configure any owned type in TPT child entity, ef creating additional foreign key to parent table.
I have configuration like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransportBase>(e => {
  e.UseTptMappingStrategy();
  e.ToTable("transports");
})
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(e => {
  e.OwnsOne(x => x.MaxSpeed, bld =>
  {
    bld.Property(x => x.Value)
      .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field)
      .HasColumnName("max_speed");
  });
  e.HasBaseType<TransportBase>();
  e.ToTable("cars"));
})
```

And it generates these constraints in table "cars":

```
constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_cars", x => x.id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "fk_cars_transports_id",
                        column: x => x.id,
                        principalTable: "transports",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "fk_transports_transports_id",
                        column: x => x.id,
                        principalTable: "transports",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

It is the same keys, except for the name.
As far as I could figure it out, this is because the key for owned-type points to the primary key for Car. But the Id field flies into TransportBase, so ef starts thinking the owner is in another table and creates a foreign key.
How can I fix it?

I tried to set shadow property, which will be principal key, but it creates unnecessary columns in table.